# Workflow assignee search result in alfresco community 5.0.d

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-maven

I'm using Alfresco Community 5.0.d and I trying to change the search picker result of workflow assignee.

Let me know how to achieve this.

Refer to below screenshot.

[image: workflow assignee search]

I want to change the search result coming in this picker.

Please let me know the file that refer to this or how to change the search result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Result coming from pickerchildren.get.js which is reside inside 
/alfresco-remote-api-5.1.f\alfresco\templates\webscripts\org\alfresco\repository\forms\

Comment: How to filter the search result ? Any heads up?

Comment: which type of filtering need in search result?

Comment: filtering based on site-a member can see only site-a member.

Comment: how would you identify that workflow is from particular site?

Comment: from people I could get their details and based on those details I could filter the out result. Then pass on the final result to be shown in workflow assignee.

Comment: how to override this file? as when I put the debugger keyword I'm not able to get the breakpoint in site? Thanks.

Comment: create same path of file in your project and place that file with your changes.

Comment: I have created this path and copied the file over there but not able to log anything (using logger.log() to check the logs on alfresco.log). Path is /Applications/alfresco-5.0.d/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/forms/pickerresults.lib.js

Comment: are you using eclips with sdk for development?

Comment: i am suggesting that try to use eclips with sdk for development.it will be easy for development and to create structure for project.

Comment: When I try to search for some files in sdk then I'm not able to search. Could you share a blog or article to do so.

Comment: sdk provide base for development.you it's not include all the files expect required files.for development you  have to override or need to create file. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utYZaVe9Nd0

Answer (score 0):

you will find this ftl at location.

```
<<alfresco-hmoe>>\tomcat\webapps\share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\form\controls\authority.ftl
```

Comment: .ftl is not the file type I'm looking for as I want to manipulate the search result. If you have a suggestion or anything then let me know.

Comment: you can override this file.
and if you wanted to view the list of particular group's member so you can do it.

Comment: I want to filter the result on basis of the organization and group.

Comment: yes, you can refer this douglas's 
https://github.com/douglascrp/alfresco-group-member-control

Comment: thank you for the link but that targets to the group where else I'm not creating any groups in alfresco. So I get result of people like in people-finder which also provide the details of the people so from that I use that information to filter the people.

Comment: Also in the link it does not clarify of how to use it? like which needs to modify or how to integrate the changes to existing alfresco from his github repo?

Comment: how could I achieve to show list of a particular group's member? Could you share the steps?